# How to retouch an old color photo with mold and damaged red channel?

Tags: photo-editing, retouching

I have a damaged photo. It has mold, and the red channel is damaged. The faces in that channel cannot be seen clearly.

I have Photoshop CS6. Is there any idea to fix that?

Original image:

[image: original]

Red channel:

[image: red channel]

Comment: Is your goal to fix the red channel or improve the entire photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely impossible, but would take a lot of meticulous, skilled brushwork with the tools such as, but not limited to, clone-stamp (**s**) key, healing and / or spot healing brushes (**j**) key to fix up some of those problems, as well as a good eye for detail.  I would be inclined to work on the full-colour image, it appears to be more 'salvageable' than the red-channel version you showed.

You may be better off to get a specialist retoucher to do it for you if there is a photolab / photographic service near you, unless you're fairly skilled and adept with the CS6 brush tools and their settings.